# Howto change cookie in an Axios request

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, axios

I don't know why, but for some reason, requests created with Axios (https://github.com/axios/) are not being caught by a chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders listener.

The idea is that I'm working on a browser extension that uses Axios to make requests on a given website with the withCredentials option set to true (so it will be validated/etc).

In a classic Chrome it's working without a problem.
But in the scenario when I use this extension and also combined with a multi-session extension (which modifies the cookies via chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders mainly), the withCredentials option is not working anymore, obviously, because attaches cookies that are invalid.

So, I wanted to "catch" myself the Axios request before headers are being sent, in order to "fix" the cookies (which are altered by multi-session extension) back to what they need to be.
But, it seems that the Axios request is not being caught by my onBeforeSendHeaders listener.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think it wont work because axios uses XMLHttpRequest so the onBeforeSendHeaders listener is bypassed, maybe you should try with the fetch api instead

You can then use the credentials: 'include' option and add your listener to intercept fetch requests and modify headers